# Play Ebean Annotation for enum object

Tags: java, playframework, enums, annotations, ebean

I need to save one List of enum object like something like that:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{

@Column
@Enumerated
@ElementCollection(targetClass = MyEnum.class)
private List<MyEnum> myEnums;

}
```

MyEnum.class

```
@EnumMapping(nameValuePairs="Z=Z, C=C, D=D")
public enum MyEnum{
//
Z("Z"),
C("C"),
D("D");

   private String description = "";
   //
    MyEnum(String description){
        this.description = description;
     }

    public String toString(){
        return description;
    }
}
```

But this annotations does not work, myEnums column does not appear into MyClass entity.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I tkink @ElementCollection does not available with play? The only solution that i have is to switch enum to Entity ? Thanks for help

Comment: I use enums like this: `@EnumValue("Z")Z,`, but I use them for single entries, not saving lists.